# Pure functions as a replacement of constant mappings?

Tags: solidity, mapping, pure

I need to create a lookup table [uint -> uint] that is constant.

Constant `mappings` or `switch-case` are not available in solidity. Are `pure` functions full of `if-else` the only option?

Any better suggestion?

**Update** Ideally, I would like an option that minimizes gas utilization

Comment: It seems from discussion below that this question is about gas optimization.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a dilemma.

You can have a mapping:

```
mapping(uint => uint) public myMap;
```

You can populate some locations in the constructor or elsewhere:

```
constructor() public {
  myMap[1] = 101;
  myMap[2] = 201;
}
```

That gives you a simple `view` function (`myMap(uint) public view returns(uint)`) that returns the number stored at an index.

You can also make `view` functions full of `if/else` if that's the best approach for your use-case.

Elaborate on the question with some hints about what you want to accomplish and possibly more specific guidance will be possible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, clearly I want to minimize gas. What do you think would be more efficient?

Comment: please note that the requirement is constant mapping to save gas cost of sload. This solution only saves the extra call to update storage values.

Answer (score 0):

The else-if function is by far less efficient that mapping in case of sparse data if there are not special criteria for searching.

If, on the contrary, you fill all the holes in the range of interest, a simple array is the best solution.